# How to open a menu link through an external button?

Tags: javascript, button

I want to open a menu through an external button:

http://jsfiddle.net/kJKq6/10/

The button can't be arranged within the html code of the menu. Im new at html and Javascript/Jquery and don't know the solution, please can anyone help?
Many Greetings

```
<button type="button">THIS BUTTON SHALL TRIGGER THE A LINK WHICH OPENS THE MENU</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your current syntax:

Insert a newline at line 16 of the javascript file and insert:

`$('button').on('click', function () {
$('.nav li').toggleClass("open");
});`

This code will cause the button to toggle the list on and off on each click.

Comment: Happy to help. Can you please mark my response as the answer? As you can see I need all the reputation I can get. Thanks.